# Magento How to get custom price and custom image value in cart?

Tags: magento

I am working on custom product design.After design the product i a setting custom price calculated on base of product height and width and custom image of product.It is showing price and custom value in $items array.But on cart page i am not able to get theses values.How i can get custom price and custom image value in cart.This is my code to set the price and image value.

```
            $item->setCustomImage($products['imageutl1']);
            $item->setCustomPrice($custom_price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($custom_price);
            // Enable super mode on the product.
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

            This is my code to get the price and image value on cart page.when i am trying to get the values on cart page using this code then it blanks the page.      
            $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

            foreach($items as $item) {


               echo $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
                 $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
                echo $item->getProduct()->custom_image();

            }       

[product_id] => 800
            [product_type] => simple
            [sku] => 111
            [name] => Test product
            [weight] => 4.0000
            [tax_class_id] => 0
            [base_cost] => 
            [is_recurring] => 0
            [is_qty_decimal] => 0
            [calculation_price] => 50.56
            [base_calculation_price] => 
            [custom_price] => 50.56
            [custom_image] => http://testimage.com/test/test.php/myimage.php
            [is_nominal] => 
            [qty_to_add] => 1
            [qty] => 1
            [qty_options] => Array
                (
                )

            [original_custom_price] => 50.56
            [small_image] => 
            [thumbnail] => 
            [is_virtual] => 
            [created_at] => 2016-04-29 05:08:15
            [updated_at] => 2016-04-29 05:08:15
            [item_id] => 159
```

Answer (score 0):

replace  `echo $item->getProduct()->custom_image();` with  `echo $item->getProduct()->getData('custom_image');`

Comment: It is not working.i have added array of product also in above code.

Answer (score 0):

Change `echo $item->getProduct()->custom_image();` to echo $item->getProduct()->getCustomImage();